# React Routes colliding when i use an optional route for my main Page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

the question may sound confusing so let me explain it to you, basically i have some routes like these,

```
<Route exact path="/:city?" component={HomePage} >

</Route>

<Route path="/Register1" component={register1}>

</Route>

<Route path="/Register2" component={register2}>

</Route>
```

so the reason home page an optional parameter is that there's a part in my header where you can choose your city and based on that param, an `api` will be called and the page will re-render with new content,
so the problem i'm facing here is when i want to go to another route, something like `/register1/` it considers it as city therefore calling api and not going to that route i was expecting,
and i can use something like this for example

```
<Route exact path="/province/:city?" component={HomePage} >

</Route>
```

but since it's my main page, it seems a little bit off,
so is there a way i can handle it without changing my other routes like `/register1` and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that React Router matches route in order that you have written it. So when it /Register2 path it matches you first route regex. You can reorder your routes, putting routes with dynamic parameters last and wrap them with Switch, which will only render 1 Route

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/Register1" component={register1} />
    <Route path="/Register2" component={register2} />
    <Route exact path="/:city?" component={HomePage} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: i honestly don't know why i didn't think of that, but Thank you, you put me out of alot of code re-writing